# Flutter: onGenerateRoute() of a nested Navigator isn't called from within a StreamBuilder

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to implement redirecting to the login/main page when the login state is changed, but when the login state is changed, nothing happens. Here is the code:

```
  return Scaffold(
    body: StreamBuilder<AuthState>(
        stream: Auth.instance.stateChanges(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
          assert(snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done);

          if (snapshot.data == AuthState.loggedIn) {
            return Navigator(
                onGenerateRoute: (_) {
                  return MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => const MainWidget(),
                  );
                }
            );
          }

          if (snapshot.data == AuthState.loggedOut) {
            return Navigator(
              onGenerateRoute: (_) {
                return MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => const LoginWidget(),
                );
              }
            );
          }

          if (snapshot.data == AuthState.verifyEmail) {
            return const EmailNotVerWidget();
          }

          throw Exception('Unknown Auth State');
        }
    ),
  );
```

Here, `Auth.instance.stateChanges()` is just a wrapper for the corresponding FirebaseAuth stream with additional logic.
As the result of debugging, it turned out that, when the login state is changed, the corresponding `Navigator` widget is returned but its `onGenerateRoute()` method isn't called, however it's called for the first time when the app is loading. I'm new in Flutter.

Upd. Here is the content of `Auth` and `AuthState`:

```
enum AuthState {
  loggedIn,
  loggedOut,
  verifyEmail,
}

class Auth {
  static final Auth _instance = Auth();

  static Auth get instance => _instance;

  UserObject? user;

  String getCurUserId() {
    return FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
  }

  Future<void> login(String email, String password) async {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
  }

  Future<void> logOut() async {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
  }

  Future<void> register(String email, String password) async {
    final credential = await FirebaseAuth.instance
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
    await credential.user!.sendEmailVerification();
  }

  Future<void> sendEmailVerEmailCurUser() async {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.sendEmailVerification();
  }

  Future<void> sendPasswordResetEmail(String email) async {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.sendPasswordResetEmail(email: email);
  }

  Stream<AuthState> stateChanges() async* {
    await for (final user in FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges()) {
      if (user == null) {
        //this.user = null;
        yield AuthState.loggedOut;
      } else {
        /* To Do: implement runtime detection of email verification */
        if (!user.emailVerified) {
          user.reload();
        }
        if (user.emailVerified) {
          /*try {
            this.user = await UserObject.loadData(user.uid);
          } catch (e) {
            print(e.toString());
          }*/
          yield AuthState.loggedIn;
        } else {
          yield AuthState.verifyEmail;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Kindly Add your AuthState class to you question

Comment: Added the content of `AuthState` and `Auth`, but it's unlikely that the error's reason is here because the `stateChanges()` stream works well, and the events are delivered as expected.

Answer (score 0):

remove the onGeneratedRuote; Not just it can be called during rebuild

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            body: StreamBuilder<AuthState>(
                stream: Auth.instance.stateChanges(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                    return const Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    );
                  }
                  assert(snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done);
                  if (snapshot.data == AuthState.loggedIn) {
                    return const MainWidget()
                  }
                  if (snapshot.data == AuthState.loggedOut) {
                    return const LoginWidget();
                  }
    
                  if (snapshot.data == AuthState.verifyEmail) {
                    const EmailNotVerWidget();;
                  }
    
                  throw Exception('Unknown Auth State');
                })
            // })
            );
      }
```

Comment: here is a snippet of how you can add onGenerated route in your MaterialApp https://gist.github.com/theodoremca/dc2e14a0138da8810b45f793e97fcbda